# entity framework adding the contents of one data table to another one in the same database

Tags: entity-framework, data-binding, entity

How do I add the records of one data table to another with the entity framework?
With data sets its like:

```
    private void sourceTabletransfer()
    {
        foreach (DataRow sourceTableRow in myDataSet.Tables["sourceTable"].Rows)
        {

            DataRow destinationTablerow = myDataSet.Tables["destinationTable"].NewRow();

            destinationTablerow["date"] = sourceTableRow["date"];
            destinationTablerow["varchar1"] = sourceTableRow["varchar1"];
            destinationTablerow["int1"] = sourceTableRow["int1"];
            myDataSet.Tables["destinationTable"].Rows.Add(destinationTablerow);
        }
        this.destinationTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.destinationTableTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet);
    }
```

How do I do the above with the entity framework?
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: If you are editing a substantial number of records, consider using an Update/Insert statement in the database. This will require only a single request to the database rather than n+1 for each record being updated. Your performance will be significantly slower using EF (or any client side technology) than an in-database solution.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have learned one more thing. The above is for a small number of records for each transfer and speed is not an issue. I will keep your advice in mind for other projects though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have two tables and their corresponding PoCo classes. Named them ParentEntity and ChildEntity.

```
foreach(var parentEntity in lstParentEntities)
{
ChildEntity  child=new ChildEntity();
child.prop1=parentEntity.Prop1;
child.prop2=parentEntity.Prop2;
child.prop3=parentEntity.Prop3;
context.AddObject(child);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and solution. I haven't thought of using POCO classes. It sure was easy.

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative - 
Working with your POCO classes named Source and Destination;

```
context.Destination.Prop1 = Source.Prop1
context.SaveChanges();
```

Also - (I would add this as a comment if i had access to it :))
you need to use context.SaveChanges(), not context.Save()